# Swift - set UIButton title regardless of state

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is there a way in Swift to change a UIButton's title/label for all states? I am setting the title of the UIButton to something, but when it is unhighlighted the label changes to what it was previously.

Thanks

Comment: Show some code, please. *"If a title is not specified for a state, the default behavior is to use the title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state."*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There isn't a method to set the title for all states at once, however if you *never* set the title for states other than the normal state, the unset states will default to the normal title.

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:)

> If a title is not specified for a state, the default behavior is to use the title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state. If the value for UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a system value.

So just call

```
button.setTitle("Button text", for:.normal)
```

Without setting the title for other states. If you need to set different titles for the other states, you'll need to set them back every time you change the button's title.

Comment: button.setTitle("title", for: UIControlState()) also works to set the title for all control states.

Comment: @ataravati - slight syntax tweak made but other than that it works just fine with my testing.

Comment: I had to specify one for `highlighted` as well.

Answer (score 13):

setTitle now takes an OptionSet - so you need to pass in an empty set.

Syntax is now:

```
button.setTitle("Button Text", for: [])
```

Comment: Thanks ! But should say that these swift team has no sense of aesthetics  and they dont get for:[] looks ugly as hell !

Comment: `.normal` is still available in Swift 3, and works just fine. But `UIControlState` is an `OptionSet` so passing `[]` means an empty set.